# different behaviour for error handling in spring boot jar and intellij idea

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, error-handling

I developed an application with spring boot.

Application contains a Global Exception handler that works fine when I run (or debug) app from Intellij IDEA.

But when I execute final jar (created by maven clean install) that error handler does not work (and all programmed exceptions that give required information to client) has been replaced with a whitepage 500 error or 500 error response in API.

this is sample resule that I want to pass to client (and it will be sent to client when I run app with IDE)

```
{
    "apierror": {
        "status": "BAD_REQUEST",
        "timestamp": {
            "month": "OCTOBER",
            "year": 2019,
            "dayOfMonth": 16,
            "dayOfWeek": "WEDNESDAY",
            "dayOfYear": 289,
            "monthValue": 10,
            "hour": 15,
            "minute": 18,
            "nano": 904000000,
            "second": 44,
            "chronology": {
                "id": "ISO",
                "calendarType": "iso8601"
            }
        },
        "code": "error.user.not-found-Username",
        "message": "error.user.not-found-Username",
        "localizedMessage": "error.user.not-found-Username",
        "subErrors": null,
        "Username": "notfoundusername"
    }
}
```

this is message returned from `java -jar` app:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-10-16T15:17:20.337+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/login"
}
```

this is error handler:

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BaseBusinessExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(BaseBusinessException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleBaseBusinessException(
        final BaseBusinessException ex,
        final HttpServletRequest request
    ) {
        ApiError apiError = new ApiError(ex.getHttpStatus());
        String acceptLanguage = request.getHeader("Accept-Language");
        if (Empty.isNotEmpty(acceptLanguage)) {
            Locale locale = new Locale(acceptLanguage);
            apiError.setLocalizedMessage(initializeMessage(ex.getErrorCode(), ex.getMessageArgs(), locale));
        }
        apiError.setCode(ex.getErrorCode());
        apiError.setMessage(initializeMessage(ex.getErrorCode(), ex.getMessageArgs(), Locale.getDefault()));
        if (Empty.isNotEmpty(ex.getMessageArgs())) {
            Map<String, Object> meta = new HashMap<>(ex.getMessageArgs());
            apiError.setMeta(meta);
        }
        return buildResponseEntity(apiError);
    }
```

and this is where exception throws:

```
        User user = userRepository.findOneByUsername(arg.getUsername());
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException(arg.getUsername());
        }
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: and what exactly is the error, and what does the Error handling look like? For all we know, you have libraries you use on your classpath in your IDE you don't have outside of it

Comment: @Stultuske I found that some exception will thrown during process of exception if code is running with java -jar, so I do know not is question is valid more or not. because one code has two different results and this was my main question

Comment: OK, so your handler only handles a certain type of Exception, while another type is thrown.